# GooglePlus Not Supporting for IOS 4.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

I have a Application Where i am integrating GooglePlus SDK to support GooglePlus.Its working fine till IOS 5.But when we run on IOS 4.3 it crashes with following Error.

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIStoryBoard
```

i am not using Any storyBoard in my Application but why this error Comes??

**As per googlePlus Documentation it supports From IOS 5**. But i just want to Know there is any way where we can make it work for IOS 4.3 as my Application Supports from IOS 4.3.

Is it Possible To support for IOS 4.3? If Yes how can we solve this.

Comment: Don't support iOS 4.3.

Comment: Drop support for iOS 4, 5, and (maybe) 6. iOS 7 is already at 80% world-wide adoption: https://mixpanel.com/trends/#report/ios_7

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from the exception, class `UIStoryBoard` is not supported in earlier versions of iOS than 5.0.

Since Google Plus SDK uses Storyboard in some way, unknown to me personally, you cannot use this SDK with any iOS that has version less than 5.0.

[Reference from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> UIStoryboard: Available in iOS 5.0 and later.

P.S. It seems to me that it is too redundant for any kind of a project to support version that is 3 releases older than current - iOS 7.